# Trying to determine which interface it will lead after user login, but my mobile apps forced closed

Tags: java, php, android, json

When I click login it just attemping to login and forced closed my apps

This is my logcat:

```
12-13 00:19:08.809: E/JSON Parser(20761): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
12-13 00:19:08.809: W/dalvikvm(20761): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
12-13 00:19:08.829: E/AndroidRuntime(20761): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
12-13 00:19:08.829: E/AndroidRuntime(20761): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-13 00:19:08.829: E/AndroidRuntime(20761):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
12-13 00:19:08.829: E/AndroidRuntime(20761):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
12-13 00:19:08.829: E/AndroidRuntime(20761):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
12-13 00:19:08.829: E/AndroidRuntime(20761):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
12-13 00:19:08.829: E/AndroidRuntime(20761):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
12-13 00:19:08.829: E/AndroidRuntime(20761):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
12-13 00:19:08.829: E/AndroidRuntime(20761):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
12-13 00:19:08.829: E/AndroidRuntime(20761):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
12-13 00:19:08.829: E/AndroidRuntime(20761): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-13 00:19:08.829: E/AndroidRuntime(20761):    at com.pmss.Login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:148)
12-13 00:19:08.829: E/AndroidRuntime(20761):    at com.pmss.Login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:1)
12-13 00:19:08.829: E/AndroidRuntime(20761):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
12-13 00:19:08.829: E/AndroidRuntime(20761):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
12-13 00:19:08.829: E/AndroidRuntime(20761):    ... 4 more
12-13 00:19:15.119: E/WindowManager(20761): Activity com.pmss.Login has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4059cf98 that was originally added here
12-13 00:19:15.119: E/WindowManager(20761): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.pmss.Login has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4059cf98 that was originally added here
12-13 00:19:15.119: E/WindowManager(20761):     at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:263)
12-13 00:19:15.119: E/WindowManager(20761):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
12-13 00:19:15.119: E/WindowManager(20761):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
12-13 00:19:15.119: E/WindowManager(20761):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
12-13 00:19:15.119: E/WindowManager(20761):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
12-13 00:19:15.119: E/WindowManager(20761):     at com.pmss.Login$AttemptLogin.onPreExecute(Login.java:130)
12-13 00:19:15.119: E/WindowManager(20761):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
12-13 00:19:15.119: E/WindowManager(20761):     at com.pmss.Login$1.onClick(Login.java:66)
12-13 00:19:15.119: E/WindowManager(20761):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
12-13 00:19:15.119: E/WindowManager(20761):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
12-13 00:19:15.119: E/WindowManager(20761):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-13 00:19:15.119: E/WindowManager(20761):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-13 00:19:15.119: E/WindowManager(20761):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-13 00:19:15.119: E/WindowManager(20761):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
12-13 00:19:15.119: E/WindowManager(20761):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-13 00:19:15.119: E/WindowManager(20761):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-13 00:19:15.119: E/WindowManager(20761):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
12-13 00:19:15.119: E/WindowManager(20761):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
12-13 00:19:15.119: E/WindowManager(20761):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Line 130: `pDialog.show();`
Line 148: `Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());`

This is my Login.java

```
public class Login extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {

private Button login, register;
private EditText email, password;

private JSONArray mComments = null;
// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// JSON parser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://XXX.XXX.X.XX:1234/PMSS/login.php";
// JSON element ids from repsonse of php script:
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
private static final String TAG_POSITION = "position";
private static final String TAG_POSTS = "posts";

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerlauncher);
    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userid);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String Username = email.getText().toString();
            String Password = password.getText().toString();
            new AttemptLogin(Username, Password).execute();
        }
    });

    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Register.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        // For the main activity, make sure the app icon in the action bar
        // does not behave as a button
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    /*
     * case R.id.login: new AttemptLogin().execute(); break; case
     * R.id.register: Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, Register.class);
     * startActivity(i); break;
     */
    default:
        break;
    }
}

class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, Integer> {

    private final String TAG = null;
    boolean failure = false;
    String res;
    String Username;
    String Password;
    String Position;
    int success;

    public AttemptLogin(String Username, String Password) {
        this.Username = Username;
        this.Password = Password;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    protected Integer doInBackground(String... args) {

        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", Username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", Password));

            Log.d("request!", "starting");
            // getting product details by making HTTP request
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST",
                    params);
            System.out.print("Here");
            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

            mComments = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);

            // looping through all posts according to the json object
            // returned
            for (int i = 0; i < mComments.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = mComments.getJSONObject(i);

                // gets the content of each tag
                // String content = c.getString(TAG_USERID);
                Position = c.getString(TAG_POSITION);

            }
            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            res = json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "JSON error", e);
            success = Integer.valueOf(0);
        }
        return success;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Integer success) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();

        if (success != null && success == 1) {
            Log.d("Login Successful!", "res: " + res);
            // save user data
            SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(Login.this);
            Editor edit = sp.edit();
            edit.putString("username", Username);
            edit.commit();
            if(Position == "user"){
                Intent user = new Intent(Login.this, MainMenu.class);
                startActivity(user);
            }
            else if(Position == "staff"){
                Intent staff = new Intent(Login.this, StaffMainMenu.class);
                startActivity(staff);
            }
            Toast.makeText(
                    Login.this,
                    res == null ? "Please enter both user id and password"
                            : res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            email.setText(null);
            password.setText(null);
        } else {
            Log.d("Login Failure!", "res: " + res);
            Toast.makeText(
                    Login.this,
                    res == null ? "Please enter both user id and password"
                            : res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}
}
```

This is my Login.php

```
<?php

require("config.inc.php");

if (!empty($_POST)) {

if(empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {

  $response["success"] = 0;
  $response["message"] = "Please fill in the login details!";
  die(json_encode($response));
}

$query = " 
        SELECT  
            email, 
            password,
    position
        FROM user 
        WHERE 
            email = :email 
    ";

$query_params = array(
    ':email' => $_POST['username'],
':position' => $_POST[],
);

try {
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
    //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());

    //or just use this use this one to product JSON data:
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error1. Please Try Again!";
    die(json_encode($response));

}

//This will be the variable to determine whether or not the user's information is correct.
//we initialize it as false.
$validated_info = false;
$login_ok = false;

//fetching all the rows from the query
$row = $stmt->fetch();
if ($row) {
    //if we encrypted the password, we would unencrypt it here, but in our case we just
    //compare the two passwords
    if ($_POST['password'] === $row['password']) {
        $login_ok = true;       
}

// If the user logged in successfully, then we send them to the private members-only page 
// Otherwise, we display a login failed message and show the login form again 
if ($login_ok) {
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Login Successful!";

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $post = array();
    $post["position"] = $row["position"];

    array_push($response["posts"], $post);
    }
echo json_encode($response);

    die(json_encode($response));
} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Invalid Credentials!";
    die(json_encode($response));
  }
}

?>
```

What am I trying to do is that I used email and password as my login id and login password, once my login.php check database for the existing user and matching the input password is same with the password that saved in database. Once it matched, it will acquire the position value from database to Login.java to determine which interface it will go like **User Main Menu** and **Staff Main Menu**.

This is my database structure

```
CREATE TABLE user (
userid INT( 30 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
name VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
email VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
password VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
mobilenumber VARCHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL ,
address VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
city VARCHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL ,
postcode VARCHAR( 10 ) NOT NULL ,
state VARCHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL ,
position VARCHAR( 30 ) NULL ,
cardbalance VARCHAR( 10 ) NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (  `userid` ) ,
UNIQUE (`email`)
) ENGINE = MYISAM
```

So, I'm not sure that the way I retrieve data is correct or not.. the position attribute is either **user** or **staff**.

Comment: It seems like you are not receiving json from your php since "Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject" you should log what your php is sending you or just run your script on a browser with your parameters and see what's the output

Comment: okok I think my php have problem, but the way I retrieve data from database through php to my android issit correct?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that but yes using json to send data to your app is a correct way if that's what you are asking. Can you post the output of your php script so we can see what's wrong with it?